# events not displayed on calendar after refresh

Tags: fullcalendar

I am having a bit of a issue with the full calendar, I can't seem to get the events displayed on the calendar after refresh, it adds it to the calendar but then if I refresh the page, it disappears, also there is 1 entry in the db for yesterday but that is also not showing in the calendar, below is the coding for the calendar, I have used pastebin to show the coding

http://pastebin.com/XxJmVa8U

I can't seem to work the issue out, hope someone can help

Thank you in advance

Ian

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem when you have once the instance of full calendar its will not create again. i have same issue like this.

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(

Before this line you may needs to add the line below.

$("#calendar").fullCalendar('destroy');

hope it will works for you.